# How to use AWS roles with Packer to create AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I'm currently building AMIs via Packer without a problem, but I am baking the AWS credentials into my scripts which is not what I want. Reading the Packer documentation they specify that if no credentials are found it can use an AWS role.

I have created the policy and the role, but it's unclear to me how to tell Packer to use this role. Do I have to pass the ARN in as a variable?

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html
Did you try this ?

Comment: I've read that page, but I don't want to specify any AWS credentials. I just want to use the role. I've found that you can pass iam_instance_profile to packer and set that to the role i've created. This works fine on the command line, but I'm trying to do this in Jenkins and I haven't figured out how to make them play nice. The Packer docs aren't clear on using iam_instance_profile. I had to dig through Github to find that.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to set the IAM role that Packer uses during AMI creation from the command-line (*e.g.* from Jenkins), then you can use variables for doing so, *e.g.* using the following in your Packer script:

```
"variables": {
  "packer_profile": "packer",
  ...
},
"builders": [
  {
    "type": "amazon-ebs",
    ...
    "iam_instance_profile": "{{user `packer_profile`}}",
    ...
  }
],
"provisioners": [
  ...
]
```

So we provide a *default* "packer" value for our `packer_profile` variable.  Then, when invoking Packer from the command-line in Jenkins, you override that default variable value using:

```
$ /path/to/packer -var packer_profile="MyNewProfileHere" ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this is the right answer but you just need to change packer_role to packer_profile

Answer (score 0):

Been scouring the web for a good answer to this and have yet to find one, so piggybacking off of this question to answer in full after struggling through it.

The first thing you want to get roles to work without needing "manual" temporary or permanent creds is a policy on your codebuild (or jenkins) service role:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:AttachVolume",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:CopyImage",
            "ec2:CreateImage",
            "ec2:CreateKeypair",
            "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
            "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:CreateVolume",
            "ec2:DeleteKeyPair",
            "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
            "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
            "ec2:DeleteVolume",
            "ec2:DeregisterImage",
            "ec2:DescribeImageAttribute",
            "ec2:DescribeImages",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
            "ec2:DescribeRegions",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeTags",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
            "ec2:DetachVolume",
            "ec2:GetPasswordData",
            "ec2:ModifyImageAttribute",
            "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
            "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
            "ec2:RegisterImage",
            "ec2:RunInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "iam:PassRole",
            "iam:GetInstanceProfile"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When you run your Packer .json you'll want to have the instance profile NAME *not* ARN in there like so:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "aws_region": "{{env `AWS_REGION`}}",
    "ami_name": "redacted-{{isotime \"02-Jan-06 03_04_05\"}}"
  },
  "builders": [{
    "name": "AWS AMI Builder",
    "type": "amazon-ebs",
    "region": "{{user `aws_region`}}",
    "source_ami": "ami-redacted",
    "instance_type": "t3.medium",
    "ssh_username": "ec2-user",
    "ami_name": "{{user `ami_name`}}",
    "tags": {
      "Name": "{{user `ami_name`}}"
    },
    "iam_instance_profile": "your_profile_name_here",
    "ami_description": "test"
  }]
}
```

I hope this helps someone down the line!

EDIT: I should mention that this needs absolutely no setup on the command-line side... unlike most the answers I've seen.