# Jenkins Packer AWS credentials validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, packer

OK Here is the scenario.

I have a Jenkins Slave in AWS and I've attached to it a Role that allows it to create EC2 resources. I found the role via the Packer github issue list. Here is the [role](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MattSurabian/5976061/raw/9b1b528b2c7d98487dfb0f1b32be53659fa8dc93/PackerPolicy.json)

I have my Packer project attempting to build on the slave. When the build starts it fails with:

> [1;31mBuild 'amazon-ebs' errored: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. 
>       For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors[0m
>
> ==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
>   --> amazon-ebs: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. 
>       For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

If I run aws configure and put in real credentials this obviously works, but I'm trying to avoid that. I have verified that the instance has the proper role attached. I have also verified that I can properly switch into this role via the command line.

What I seem to be missing is that with the role associated with the instance and packer specifying the role with: 'iam_instance_profile' why this continues to fail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you provide the Packer `.json` config file you're using?

Comment: I've put it in this Gist https://gist.github.com/davidfic/dd16836a5ec406473ea29698e6b3021f

Comment: So then your Jenkins `packer` command is providing the role to use via `-var packer_profile="foo"` command-line options, yes?  Or do you rely on the default "packer" value there?

Comment: Here is my command:   packer build -var aws_access_key=<<key>> -var aws_secret_key=<<secret>> -var region=us-west-2 -var vpc_id=<<vpc_id>> -var subnet_id=<<subnet_id>> -var security_group_ids=<<sg-id>> -var source_ami=<<ami id>> -var ssh_username=ubuntu -var instance_type=t2.small -var iam_instance_profile=PackerJenkins -var packer_profile=PackerJenkins

Comment: So the policy `.json` is named "PackerPolicy.json" (implying a role name of "PackerPolicy"), but the role name you are setting on the command-line is "PackerJenkins"?

Comment: I got some advice from a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311048/how-to-use-aws-roles-with-packer-to-create-amis?noredirect=1#comment60247173_36311048_)  Maybe I'm misreading what they had there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107974/discussion-between-david-ficociello-and-castaglia).

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of help from Castaglia I was able to get this to work. There seemed to be something wrong with the Role I had created. I deleted it and recreated it with the same name and same policy attached. After that it worked fine.

To note, I believe the Packer instructions have an error. They list the following as all that is needed for the role:

```
{
"Statement": [{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action" : [
    "ec2:AttachVolume",
    "ec2:CreateVolume",
    "ec2:DeleteVolume",
    "ec2:CreateKeypair",
    "ec2:DeleteKeypair",
    "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
    "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
    "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
    "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
    "ec2:CreateImage",
    "ec2:CopyImage",
    "ec2:RunInstances",
    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
    "ec2:StopInstances",
    "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
    "ec2:DetachVolume",
    "ec2:DescribeInstances",
    "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
    "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
    "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
    "ec2:DescribeImages",
    "ec2:RegisterImage",
    "ec2:CreateTags",
    "ec2:ModifyImageAttribute"
  ],
  "Resource" : "*"
}]
}
```

But I believe you need one more piece:

```
{
    "Sid": "PackerIAMPassRole",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iam:PassRole",
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
}
```

Doing this allowed me to assume the role and build what I needed.